# How to update encoded password functionally in mysql with spring boot data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created CRUD operation with Spring Boot Data JPA. I'm doing with my experiment with change password functionally with role, if user forgot the old password, admin can change password user to default (ex: defaultpassword), I've tried this with put the password as plain text with @PutMapping Controller but because the password encoder it can't be logged in after changing the password as plain text. How the proper way to do it?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Use `{plain}defaultpassword`. Assuming you use a recent version of Spring and have not configured the `PasswordEncoder` explicitly. Else inject the `PasswordEncoder` into your controller and encode the password before storing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just inject the `PasswordEncoder` into the controller class for changing the password.

```java
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @PutMapping(...)
    public void put(...) {
        String encoded = encoder.encode(password);

        //update
    }

}
```